# Hive substr function start Index Issue

Tags: apache-spark, hiveql

I am using hive 2.11 (hive context) with Apache spark 1.6.2.
I am observing a unexpected behavior with hive substr function.

Documentation says that:-

> **substr(string|binary A, int start, int len) substring(string|binary A,
>   int start, int len)**      Returns the substring or slice of the byte array
>   of A starting from start position with length len. For example,
>   substr('foobar', 4, 1) results in 'b' (see
>   [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr]).

My Observation:-

```
1. select substr('Sakila' ,0,3) from <table>; => returns 'Sak'

2. select substr('Sakila' ,1,3) from <table>; => returns 'Sak'
```

So my question is:-

1. What is my start index 0 or 1?
2. Is it a known issue?

I tried executing above query here: http://demo.gethue.com/beeswax/#query
but got the same result.

Comment: Though zero is not mentioned, the documentation that you link does describe using negative numbers in substring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the foobar example, the index of the first letter is 1.

If you have a nonpositive number m, your substring starts m positions 'left' of 1.

Example:

```
select substring('abcdefgh',-1,3)
h
```

From this perspective, you could see that 0 positions left of 1 is still 1, and therefore the commands give the same result.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Accepting the answer.

Comment: Excellent explanation!